# Javascript Rot13 function not working at all

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

"Create a function that takes a string and returns the string ciphered with Rot13. If there are numbers or special characters included in the string, they should be returned as they are. Only letters from the latin/english alphabet should be shifted, like in the original Rot13 "implementation"."

I wrote this code but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
function rot13(message){
  var solved = "";
  for (i=0; i<message.length; i++){
    var asciiNum = message[i].charCodeAt();
    if (asciiNum >= 65 && asciiNum <= 77) {
      solved += String.fromCharCode(asciiNum + 13);
      } else if (asciiNum >= 78 && asciiNum <= 90) {
        solved += String.fromCharCode(asciiNum - 13);
      } else {
        solved += message[i];
      }
    }
    return solved;
}
```

By using the input: "Ruby is cool!" for testing the code, the expected output should be "Ehol vf pbby!". What I get instead is "Euby is cool!"

Comment: What is the expected output and what are you getting?

Comment: _“but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:”_ – then go read [ask] first of all please. What you did wrong _asking_ here, is you failed to describe _how_ it goes wrong, and you did not provide example data either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only takes into account upper case characters.

The ASCII values of lower case characters start at 97.
https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the code in this way:

```
function rot13(text) {
    var source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var target = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM";
    var out = "";
    for (var l=0; l<text.length; l++) {
             var p = source.indexOf(text[l]);
             out += p>0 ? target[p] : text[l];
        }
    return out;
}
```